# How to get OpenID info in ASP.NET core WEB API controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, claims

There are two applications:

1. OneLogin identity provider with enabled OpenID connect.
2. My ASP.NET core WEB API which is resource server for frontend application.

Initially I had only authorization logic implemented, using the following code:

```
serviceCollection
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = clientId;
                options.Authority = authority;
            });
```

I set [AuthorizeAttribute] for my controller and the authorization logic worked fine.
Now I need to get information about user in my controller. For this I would like to use OpenID info. I modified my code by adding OpenID connect:

```
serviceCollection
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = clientId;
                options.Authority = authority;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.Authority = authority;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            });
```

But I still see only access_token claims in my controller (User.Identity). What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

you could add the desired claims to the access token (In the ApiScope or ApiResources) and then access then through the AddJwtBearer in the API.

Alternatively, you can take the access-token and sent it to the token [introspection](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/endpoints/introspection/) endpoint, from the response you can get more details about the user. You can also manually call the userinfo endpoint using the access token. However, AddJWtBearer won't call these endpoints for you. The helper classes in [IdentityModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can help you to do that.

Adding AddOpenIdConnect to the API, just to get the user details is the wrong approach.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. Could you provide more info about option 1? I don't understand how can I add claims to the access_token if I don't have control on the token generation.

With my current understanding of the flow, I need to manually call userinfo endpoint to obtain the required data.

Comment: that is OpenID provider specific, how you go about to do that and what endpoints it provides.

Comment: This answer is kind of vague. some code examples whoud help

Comment: I have no experience with OneLogin but you would configure and add the necessary claims to the user-data stored in OneLogin  (i assume your users are stored in there). That is where you configure what goes into the ID and access token... There are many options for how to address this. Also some tradeoffs with cookie/token size and other considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `HttpContext` like this (don´t need to do it this way, but its a bit nicer to call in your controller you could put the code straight into your controller).

```
public static class AuthExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserId(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "id").Value;
    }

    public static UserRole GetUserRole(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("User not set on httpContext.");

        var roleStr = httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
        return (UserRole) Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRole), roleStr);
    }
}
```

Then You can call those from your controller `var userId = Request.HttpContext.GetUserId();`. Note that what´s in the Claims depends on what you did put into into it when creating the token. You might not have a role for instance. If you don´t know, you can lookup what your tokens contain by copy/pasting one into jwt.io.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max. But my problem is different. I see claims only from access_token, but I need to get claims from id_token. If I understand correctly, ASP.NET middleware should do request to "userinfo" endpoint to get this information, but I am not sure. Of course I can do the request manually, but is there ability to configure the middleware to do this request and put claims into HttpContext?

Comment: According to this https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1449 you need to use ```ClaimActions.MapJsonKey``` to select the claims you care about. Others won´t be mapped.